# Working out total price of Journey cost with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, html, math, percentage

Okay so i have to take the number of adults inputted by the user and times it against the journey cost which I've got, however i also need to take the number of children and give them a flat  %20 discount rate across all journeys, Here is my code.

HTML

```
<select id = "journeyList">
<option name ="Bristol " value="40">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
<option name ="London " value="35" >Bristol - London</option>
<option name ="Glasgow " value="70" >Glasgow - Manchester</option>
</select><br><br>

Number of Adults: 
<form>
<input type = "number" name ="adult" id="ofAdults" value="" required><br>
Number of Children:<br>
<input type = "number" name ="child" id="ofChild" value="" required>

<button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button><br>
    Journey Price:
    <div id="priceBox"></div><br>
    Number of Adults:
    <div id="adultsBox"></div><br>
    Number of Children:
    <div id="childBox"></div><br>
    Total Cost:
    <div id="totalBox"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function BookingFare() { 

    var journeyList = document.getElementById("journeyList");
    var price =journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value;
    var Adults = document.getElementById("ofAdults").value;
    var Children = document.getElementById("ofChild").value;
    //var total = price * Adults;

    document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById('adultsBox').innerHTML = Adults;
    document.getElementById('childBox').innerHTML = Children;
    document.getElementById('totalBox').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Should i be looking to do if statements? Thankyou for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Reducing by 20% is the same as multiplying by .8, so:

```
document.getElementById('totalBox').innerHTML =
   (Adults * price) + (Children * price * .8);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the modified JS file:

```
function BookingFare() { 

    var journeyList = document.getElementById("journeyList");
    var price =journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value;
    var Adults = document.getElementById("ofAdults").value;
    var Children = document.getElementById("ofChild").value;
    var total = price * Adults + (price - (price * 0.2) *  Children);

    document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById('adultsBox').innerHTML = Adults;
    document.getElementById('childBox').innerHTML = Children;
    document.getElementById('totalBox').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript number literals use `.`, not `,`, as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question "how do i calculate total price knowing number of adults and number of childs"? Maybe try something like `(Adult+0.8*Children)*price` (but i think you'd be able to find that by yourself..)

The only thing you have to consider is what will you do if the user doesn't input a number for the number of adults or the number of children (maybe set `Children` to `0` if `document.getElementById("ofChild").value=""` for example.)

You could ask yourself also about how to deal with wrong inputs (letters, etc)

Comment: Just want to add, in case of handling the incorrect answers, the simplest way here would be to do `var Adults = Number(document.getElementById("ofChild").value) || 0;`.